# Celery works without broker and backend running

Tags: redis, rabbitmq, celery

I'm running Celery on my laptop, with rabbitmq being the broker and redis being the backend. I just used all the default settings and ran `celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info`, then it all worked. The workers can get jobs done and I get fetch the execution results by calling `result.get()`. My question here is that why it works even if I didn't run the rebbitmq and redis servers at all. I did not set the accounts on the servers either. In many tutorials, the first step is to run the broker and backend servers before starting celery.

I'm new to these tools and do not quite understand how they work behind the scene. Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: is `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER` set to `True` ?

Comment: @scytale I don't see that field in my config. Can you explain what it does? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I just realized that redis and rabbitmq automatically run after installation or shell startup. They must be running for celery to work.